# PHP session_start fails

Tags: php, session, xampp

I'm trying to start the session in a header page in my webiste. But it seems there might be some sort of bug because it fails with the following error:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(\xampp\tmp\sess_a7430aab4dd08d5fc0d511f781f41fe5, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in D:\Development\PHP\tt\Include\header.php on line 3
```

I'm using the default settings for xampp, everything is straight out of the box. For some reason its failing to open the file. however when i go to the directory with the session files in it, the files are there, they are just empty. Is this a bug? or am I doing something wrong?

php version 5.2.8

Comment: @SHOBAN I don't think there is anything that can be done in calling session_start() that can cause this error, there is no need to see the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This means that you don't have the correct permissions to either read or write the files in the temp directory.

If you on linux then do this

```
sudo chmod -R 755 \xampp\tmp //or should it be 775
```

On windows do this as an administrator

```
attrib -r -a C:\xampp\tmp /S
```

Comment: It was giving me a file not found error, so I added /D at the end and it went through. Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem

Comment: If I right click on the folder and go to properties, read only is checked. But if I uncheck it, hit apply, and then right click and go back to properties, its checked again.

Comment: Than you probably don't have the proper privelages to change the permissions.

Comment: I'm logged in as administrator. I solved the problem by changing the directory it uses in php.ini

Answer (score 13):

First stop the Xampp Server.

session.save_path = "\xampp\tmp"

and change it to look like this

session.save_path = "C:\xampp\tmp"

Restart the Xampp Server.

That’s it now your session should work as expected.

Comment: Problem is the directory must exist.

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer. Unless your answer add relevant information, or corrects a mistake found in the current answers, you shouldn't post an answer.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha There is a comment to the accepted answer that states that it didn't solve the problem. So adding an actually working answer should not be a mistake.

Comment: Accepted answer didnt solve my problem, whereas this post does. So thumbs up for this one.

Comment: Like for Sgali, this fixed it for me (Okay I changed to directory to a path outside C:\ but still, thanks for the hint!)

Comment: This is the real solution.
I came across this problem after running an app(virtual host) in a drive(F:) different from the one where xampp(C:) is installed. Then xampp was looking for the session folder on the F: drive.

Answer (score 0):

As Selular88 mentioned, Adding the path works and fix this issue. You can also check the path using

```
// This will output your current path.
echo session_save_path() ;
```