# Session_start failing because lack of permissions

Tags: php

I'm using Windows 7 with an Administrator account. I have Xampp installed at C:\xampp.

I have the same problem that [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670595/php-session-start-fails), and I tried:

- Uncheck "read only" boxes to all files and folders
- attrib -r -a C:\xampp\tmp /S /D (without the /D gives file not found)
- Selected "everyone" in security just to make sure.

My xampp and tmp folder are now probably the unsafest folder in my computer, but I still get

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]:
>   open(\xampp\tmp\sess_1fcpeje5cqaopevmlclif9ejc0, O_RDWR) failed: No
>   such file or directory (2)

Which I think it means that the folder is still not writable.
My code is just as

```
<?php
session_start();
....
>
```

Comment: `\xampp\…` is not `C:\xampp\…`. Check *session.save\_path*.

Comment: @Gumbo php.ini have that as default configuration. That can't be "wrong". Save path is the same. But I will try. Anyway it works if I change the temp folder in other place, but that's not the solution I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 7):

Now, you can do follow some step:

1. Stop apache
2. Go to php.ini file
3. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> then type "session.save_path" into Find Watch textbox.
4. You can set value to your tmp folder. for example : "D:\xampp\tmp".
5. Now you can re start your apache.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using a 64 bit system, I highly recommend installing wamp 64 bit.
2. If you want to stick to XAMPP try the following:

   1. use the function ini_set to set the path to the sessions to be saved.
   2. a path that works is c:\windows\temp

If all failed try install your wamp or xamp on d drive or any other drive but c.
this will guarantee permission on normal drives.